# Passing too many arguments works sometimes, why?

Tags: function, arguments, glsl

I was using this site for testing: http://glslsandbox.com/

This shows the color red:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

void main( void ) {
    vec4 c = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = c;
}
```

I can change the color line in different ways, sometimes it compiles and sometimes not:

```
    vec4 c = vec4(1.0, vec2(0.0), vec4(1.0)); // works
    vec4 c = vec4(vec2(1.0), vec2(0.0), 0.0); // doesn't compile
    vec4 c = vec4(1.0, vec2(0.0), vec2(1.0)); // works
    vec4 c = vec4(1.0, vec4(0.0), 0.0); // doesn't compile
    vec4 c = vec4(vec4(1.0), vec4(0.0)); // doesn't compile
```

Why does passing too many arguments work sometimes and sometimes not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML) - 5.4.2. Vector and Matrix Constructors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#constructors):

> [...] The arguments will be consumed left to right, and each argument will have all its components consumed, in order, before any components from the next argument are consumed. [...]
> In these cases, there must be enough components provided in the arguments to provide an initializer for every component in the constructed value. It is a compile-time error to provide extra arguments beyond this last used argument.

Hence, the following is allowed:

```c
vec4 c = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, vec4(4.0));
```

```c
vec3 c = vec3(vec4(4.0));
```

However, the following is not allowed because the last element in the constructor (`vec4(4.0)`) causes a compile time error (*It is a compile-time error to provide extra arguments beyond this last used argument.*):

```py
vec3 c = vec3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, vec4(4.0));
```

---

The reason for this is that it should be allowed to construct a *smaller* vector (or matrix) from a *larger* vector (or matrix). For instance:

```c
vec4 v4;
```

```c
vec3 v3 = vec3(v4);
```